# what are pros and cons between setting up aws codepipeline on a dedicated account to the individual(application) accounts itself

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, aws-codepipeline, continuous-delivery

I'm trying to figure out what are the pros and cons between setting up aws codepipeline on a dedicated account to the individual(application) accounts itself in the long run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say **sepration of responsibilities**.

If you have your (production) application in a **separate account**, you can minimize any accidental manual/accidental modifications to it by users who operate on development or testing environments. The account will have very strict access rules and it should be basically immutable. This de-facto provides a   "physical" barrier between your application environment and development/testing environments.

In contrast, when you put everything into the **same account**, the natural border between the application and everything else diminishes. This could lead to a **number of issues**, such as:

- security concerns (who can access your running application),
- accidental modifications of running application,
- confusion of what resources are part of the application and which are part of the pipeline or development environment,
- non-well defined responsibilities of who does want in such a account, and more.